# Handlebars.js and Webpack - precompile templates

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, handlebars.js, webpack

I'm using `Backbone.js`, `Handlebars.js` and `Webpack` for my website.
I used to use `Require.js` instead of `Webpack`. I have the following files:

**template.js**

```
define({
    structure:      "structure.html",
    home:           "home.html"

});
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
resolve: {
        extensions: ['', '.js', '.json'],

        alias: {
            root: path.resolve( __dirname ),
            "router": path.resolve( __dirname ) + "/www/js/router",
            "templates": path.resolve( __dirname ) + "/www/js/templates",
            "handlebars": path.resolve( __dirname ) + "/node_modules/handlebars/dist/handlebars",
        "templates_html": path.resolve( __dirname ) + "/www/templates"
        }    
    },
```

**view.js**

```
define( ['jquery', 'underscore', 'backbone', "utils" ], 
       function($, _, Backbone, Utils) {

    var View = Utils.Page.extend({

        constructorName: "View",
        id: "home",

        initialize: function() {
            this.template = Utils.templates.home; // this is what I need

        },

        render: function () {
            this.$el.html(     this.template( this.model.toJSON() )    );
            return this;
        },

    });

    return View;

});
```

I'd like to compile all templates with `Handlebars.js` at start of my website.
When I was using `Require.js` I was used to doing something like this:

**utils.js**

```
define( ['jquery', 'underscore', 'backbone', 'handlebars', 'templates'], 
       function($, _, Backbone, Handlebars, Templates) {

    var Utils = {
        templates: {}
    };

    for (var t in Templates) {
      Templates[t] = "text!" + Templates[t];
    }

    require(_.values(Templates), function() {

        var fragments = _.object(_.keys(Templates), arguments);

        // precompile all the fragments
        for (var t in fragments) {
          Utils.templates[t] = Handlebars.compile(fragments[t]); /* <Handlebars> */
        }

    });
    return Utils;
});
```

How can I do something like that in **utils.js** with `webpack`?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this handlebars loader for web pack https://github.com/pcardune/handlebars-loader/blob/master/README.md full info is given there but basically set the loader to compile all of your html files in your templates folder or rename them from .html to .hbs or .handlebars then simple require them in your modules and they will be compiled.